# How to add matlab.linterconfig file to VSCode?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code, configuration, settings

VSCode displays warning of "cannot open or read the Code Analyzer settings from file"

The terminal also displays "zsh: missing end of string"

[image]

I tried adding different file paths but I can't seem to make it work